# Firebase change file name on download

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to download a file but before that i would like to remove the prefix I've put

Current Code:

```
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, props.fullPath))
    .then((url) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = (event) => {
        const blob = xhr.response;
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
      window.open(url, '_blank', 'noreferrer').focus();

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("download file error ", error)
    });
```

E.g:

file name in database:
Data.csv7d931632-a562-4d7c-9b9c-d00a90a545e0

file name on download:
Data.csv